# Mark task complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement a simple "Mark as complete" feature on a todo list but having difficulty based on my app setup. I start a tutorial that had the tasks nested in a list, I am going about it slightly differently but cannot figure out the correct route.

I have no nesting but simple associations i.e. user has many tasks and tasks belongs to user. I have a completed (boolean) column in my task table

The complete action in my tasks controller

```
def complete
 @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
 @task.completed = true
 @task.save
 redirect_to tasks_path
end
```

Route file

```
match '/tasks/complete' => 'tasks#complete'
```

Index View

```
<% current_user.tasks.each do |task| %> 
 <%= task.description %> | <%= link_to "Complete", complete_task_path(task) %>
<% end %>
```

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the line in your route file look like:

```
match '/tasks/complete' => 'tasks#complete', as: 'complete_task'
```

Note that this may do what you are looking for, but will be insecure as HTTP GET requests don't get any protection by default from cross-site request forgery attacks. Besides that, generally speaking, you only want to use HTTP GET requests for reading, not writing/updating as you're doing here. It's probably more appropriate to use an HTTP PUT. You can adjust your routes like this:

```
match '/tasks/complete' => 'tasks#complete', as: 'complete_task', via: :put
```

... and then do something like this:

```
<%= task.description %> | <%= link_to "Complete", complete_task_path(task), method: :put %>
```

I haven't tested the above exactly, but should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks again Chris currently getting this error 
Couldn't find Task with id=complete [WHERE "tasks"."user_id" = 1]

Comment: Oh, yes, that would be a problem. I think you actually want to have something like this in your routes.rb:

match '/tasks/complete/:id' => 'tasks#complete', as: 'complete_task', via: :put

And you may need to move that line to be before resources :tasks if you have that in your routes file as well...